# Problem with running a file in the terminal

Tags: linux

I am watching a video an he is saying to type “Ipython” then “run” and the file name (which was saved in test editor). When I do this, I get an error message saying “name ‘run’ is not defined”

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What video - can you link to it and the relevant time point?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know `ipython`, so i assume it is an interactive command interpreter.

Then you would need to ensure these steps:

1. Save your python code (`file.py` or similar) to a dedicated directory, lets say `/home/username/file.py`.
2. Change (`cd`) to that directory: `cd /home/username`.
3. `run` that file from within the python interpreter: `ipython ./file.py`, where `./` tells the interpreter to look for the file in the current directory.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ipython` is broken in some way; that `run` functionality is definitely part of its parsing capabilities.

Either you're not running the right program, or your installation is broken, or you've got some environment set that makes it impossible for ipython to load its startup scripts; either way, sadly hard to help you from here.

Honestly, though: python is not matlab, and instead of typing `run filename.py` into ipython, you could also just run your script from an IDE. You'd not be writing python code from a pure text editor, anyways, as that makes keeping indents consistent (and that's necessary for your Python to even work!).